# How could I generate the parameter of 'selective dynamics' in POSCAR with ASE?

Tags: vasp, software-assistance, atomic-simulation-environment

I often use selective dynamics to do structure optimization in VASP, but I am not sure how to do it when using ASE, it seems I could use the [constraint](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/constraints.html) class to tell ASE what I want to do.
My question is:
When I use the `constraint` class, does ASE generate the POSCAR that includes the `selective dynamics` parameter? Or it is like the case of [optimizer](https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/gettingstarted/tut02_h2o_structure/h2o.html), ASE could just use VASP as a calculator, and set the constraint outside the loop of VASP calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FixAtoms` constraint will be turned into the selective dynamics tags as "F F F".  ASE will also convert selective dynamics to this constraint when reading.

I think the `FixedPlane` and `FixedLine` could in theory also work, but I am not sure they do since they support directions not aligned with the X, Y, and Z axis. If you need this and it doesn't work (just give it a try), you might ask on the ASE Matrix chat to see if someone is willing to add it for you or tell you how to change it yourself.